# How do I know if the wood I picked up on Craigslist is treated?

Tags: wood, pressure-treated

I picked up some cheap wood that someone was getting rid of. He said it was used for a deck, and I can see it is painted red. How do I know if it is treated? (Also, anyone know what kind of wood it is?)

The wood in question is the small block sitting on top of oak veneer plywood.[image]

Comment: Similar query to [this previous Question](https://woodworking.stackexchange.com/questions/6545/help-identifying-old-fence-wood) which as you can see was closed as off-topic. Wood IDs similarly are outside the scope of this SE, but that is a piece of fast-growth commercial softwood, referred to generically as SPF (spruce, pine, fir) because wood from the three species can be considered so interchangeable.

Comment: Ah... That's really too bad about it being SPF... He pointed me at this when I said "do you have any hardwood" but I'm fairly inclined to be believe you since it seems just as soft (when tested via my fingernail) as the cheap 2x4's I have around.

Should I delete the question, or leave it here for the mods to close?

Comment: Interesting thing about hardwood/softwood distinction: It really is more about how they grow than their inherent hardness. There can be very soft hardwoods (basswood, for example) and very hard softwoods (yew, which is harder than hard maple on the Janka scale).

Comment: Not treated, btw. You'll see hatches on the face/edge where they are essentially trying to inject the mystery substance (cca/quant/whatever), and you'll see a difference in coloration between the edges and the core.

Comment: Not sure I agree necessarily with @AloysiusDefenestrate - I've never seen treated timber in my country with the hatch/needle marks (though I've seen in photos, so I do know some countries do this). Also color is a somewhat, but not totally reliable guide - different chemicals mandated in different countries/time periods have different color profiles. Color can indicate it was treated, but the lack of color doesn't prove it wasn't treated.  If it is pine, I would say it's dark enough to look treated and I can't imagine untreated pine being used for decking (or looking that good afterwards!)

Comment: I should have specified that I was talking about North America. Sorry.

Comment: If it was used for decking, assume it was treated. Anything out in the elements better be treated or naturally moisture resistant (like cedar).

Answer (score 1):

Since this is US/Canada, when you talk about "treated" I assume you're talking about CCA (Copper-Chrome-Arsenic).

The answer is simple enough - buy a test kit. Google on arsenic wood test kit. For instance, on Amazon you can find [Industrial-Test-Systems-481396-W-Arsenic](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00DIJ91GE) and Walmart sells [Arsenic-481396-W-Quick-Wood-Field-Testing-Kit](https://www.walmart.com/ip/Arsenic-481396-W-Quick-Wood-Field-Testing-Kit/47714541?wmlspartner=wlpa&selectedSellerId=1148&adid=22222222227034975956&wl0=&wl1=g&wl2=c&wl3=75434718394&wl4=pla-175405973074&wl5=1021883&wl6=&wl7=&wl8=&wl9=pla&wl10=112562587&wl11=online&wl12=47714541&wl13=&veh=sem)

Comment: CCA is not the only type of treatment, and i believe it's actually been phased out - so depending on the age of this wood, it may be treated but not at all CCA. This wood looks like southern yellow pine, which is frequently treated (non-CCA) and used for decking. I would assume that is the case here.

Comment: @DavidZemon - Pay attention to aaron's comment. I'm not sure if you really did mean CCA when you said treated. If you just assumed that "treated" means CCA, then you need to do some research.

Comment: Good to know. The fact that it's SPF ruins my original plans for this anyway (cutting board), but I'll remember that about CCA if I never need to test something in the future.